# Python flask with Angular route not not working through dist folder

Tags: python, angular, flask

I have an angular application serving on python flask at the backend. My folder structure looks like:
[image]

I build the angular application using: `ng build --prod --build-optimizer --base-href=/static/` 
I am manually copying the files to static and templates folder 
My main.py contents:

```
@app.route('/')
@cross_origin()
def root():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__";
   pythoncom.CoInitialize()
   serve(app, port=5003)
```

Localhost just runs perfectly fine at: http://localhost:4200/dashboardpage 
But when I try to run it via: `http-server --path ./python-files --cors true --baseHref /static/`, I get a page not found. The Url being hit is: http://10.105.114.205:8080/static/dashboardpage 
My main aim is to have this application deployed on a server, where I will have a flask server running to serve my angular application, but before doing this I need to make sure that the routing is working fine through http-server.